# Posting a photo to Facebook fan page as user. iOS Facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to post a photo to Facebook page from user using Facebook SDK 3.1.
When I'm using the following code to create upload image request:

```
FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/${FAN_PAGE_ID}/photos/" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.imageToShare, @"source", nil] HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Image goes directly to **user's timeline**, not the page's one.

But when I'm posting a link:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/${FAN_PAGE_ID}/feed/" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://stackoverflow.com", @"link", nil] HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Link posts correctly to the facebook page.

To open a session I'm using code:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"photo_upload", nil]
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
...
                          }];
```

*I know that `openActiveSessionWithPermissions` is deprecated, using it for equal SSO behaviour on iOS 5 and 6.*

**UPDATE**

Or is it possible to upload a photo with access token substitution? Using page access token instead of user access token. If yes, how can I get page access token programmatically without forcing user to log in as page administrator?

What would you advise me to do?
Thanks!

BR.
Eugene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos says,

> “You can post photos to a Page's Wall by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/photos with the publish_stream **and manage_pages permissions** […]”

Sounds like a “normal” user is not allowed to post images to a page’s wall via the API.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I found this thing http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html and I can upload a photo to Facebook Page album using this. I want the same behaviour in iOS app. Do you know how they do this?

Comment: They are getting a page access token first. So you’d have to get manage_pages permission from the user first (the user has to be admin of that page of course), and then get the page access token to upload a photo.

Comment: @CBroe : Can you add example codes of how to obtain `manage_pages` permission ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: You just ask for it via the `scope` parameter in the login flow.