# Why can't I post to a fan page from my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I want to post images from my iOS app to a single Facebook fan page. I'm new to facebook-sdk. I can post to a user's page with no issue using either facebook sdk or social framework, but what I cannot work out is posting to a fan page. I have set up a fan page and have set it to allow posts from anyone but when I try it with the url `/pageID/picture` it won't work. It'll work for admins, but I want non-admins to be able to post.

What do I need to do?

---

I can post image but it end up only in my images . no matter what url  I Use
fb /me/photo or /fan_page_id/photo the images only end up in my image folder not on the wall please any help would be great I can find 1000's of questions on this but no answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it I never added this key to my options dict 
 ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
In the Account framework header it has it marked as optional but I could not request any thing other then read permission but after adding this key to my options dictionary it worked I dont know why this makes a difference but it fix my issue with out it I could only post to my images folder and I could not request permission other then read . After adding key I can post to wall and fan page wall and request any permission I need.

Comment: Im getting the post through but Its showing as post by other on fan page when I send it to url fb /page_id/feed dose any one know what to use instead of feed to post to wall

Answer (score 0):

In your Fan Page, Look for "Edit Page" option. In that part, click on "Manage Permission".

In **Manage Permission** page,

Check

**Posting Ability:**

1> Everyone can post to <> timeline

2> Everyone can add photos and videos to <> timeline

Also take a username for your fan page to refer your user in a easier way.

**Update**

You have to create an facebook application for the requirement.

Following three links may help you -

1> [Posting a photo to Facebook fan page as user. iOS Facebook SDK 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687144/posting-a-photo-to-facebook-fan-page-as-user-ios-facebook-sdk-3-1)

2> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

3> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

Actually, the `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` permissions are important.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks heaps You save my butt Ive been googling for a week and So many people ask the same question but all answers are for fan pages for admin user

Comment: I dont have a app id setup in facebook as Im trying to post as non admin and have each user of my app pst to the same fan page , I didnt set up a facebook app id so I need to setup one .???

Comment: Every thing my reading has to do with user permission and to pages of theirs . Would it work if I just used the social framework to login user then send a SLRequest to post image to fan page url ???

Comment: User should have manage_pages permission to post the photos to the pages if they post photos in the fan page wall.

Comment: Ive never found a service so hard to use I can not event get samples to work . I was told to first request a email permission as I can only request a read permission then I have to request a write permission so I place a 2nd request block in the first then my SLrequest wont work unless it is in the block as well but when I put it in the block I still get error