# Can users of my IOS app post to my facebook page without having explicit permission?

Tags: ios, facebook, post, facebook-page

Im an IOS developer but noob to facebook development.  Ive been reading 'pages' and 'permissions' documentation but Im unsure about two basic points.

**The requirement**:  I want to put a 'share' button or similar in my IOS app that will then post to my facebook page as 'the page' **on behalf** of whoever is using my app.

Ideally I would like to give my IOS app permission to post to my page (by virtue of its knowledge of facebook app id and secret key), regardless of who is using my IOS app - the end user may not even have a facebook account.

**My confusion:**  Is this possible?  From my reading of the Pages documentation, I think facebook will require that the end user - the person using my IOS app - will need to login to facebook and aquire permissions to post to my page.  They wont be able to 'anonymously' use my IOS app to post to my page.

**My second confusion**: If my assumption is correct and facebook will require the end user to login to facebook before proceeding, will it grant permission to any old tom, dick and harry, or must that user *explicitly already have permission to post to my page* by being previously set up with an appropriate role?

**summary:** I want to be able to trust my IOS app to post to my page on behalf of any end user.  If the end user must login first to facebook in order to obtain some ad-hoc permission to post to the page temporarily, then I guess thats a necessary evil.  IF the end user must have explicit permission already set up to post to the page, then thats a deal breaker for me.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Posting as the page requires a page access token. But since that allows to perform a lot of other stuff on your page as well (changing settings, etc.), a page access token should never be exposed in client-side code - so you would need to do this server-side.

Comment: Thank you, and to be clear, the user does not have to have been explicitly identified with page access permission (such as being given admin status for the page or something) -- any old user can be granted permission to get page_access token on an ad-hocbasis by my app?

Comment: A page access token has to be granted by a page admin.

Comment: In other words there is no way to grant ad-hoc posting ability to any old user of my app to a facebook page I administrate without manually making each such user able to post to my page.  (which would be an admin nightmare obviously)

Comment: The user can post as themselves, but if you want them to post as the page, that requires a page access token. (And those do not belong into client-side code, meaning in that case you would have to do this server-side anyway.)

Comment: ah, this is getting me down.  So I am trying to post from my ios app to my page of which I am the admin (obviously).  I can get an user access token with the login button from the SDK.  It shows these 5 permissions including publish_pages and manage_pages.  I can ask for a page access token for my page - I get the same token.  perhaps because it is a test page ?  Anyway, when I try to post to my pages feed, I get an error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action'  (if I use the graph explorer) or 'insufficient scope' if I call the graph api from my code

Comment: I suspect it could be becaue I tested it first without the user just granting the normal 3 read permissions, not publish and manage page?  Buuut, even if I include those publish permissions when I log the user out and then in again, it doesnt ask the user for those permissions, it just says the 'user has already authorized this app' in the login dialog, and has a 'continue' button.  its driving me nuts, I want the user to have to acknowledge the permissions I am asking it for, but somehow it just wont

Comment: Your app user doesn’t need to grant your app manage_pages - that would give you access to _their_ pages, but you want to post on _your_ page (which that app user is presumably not an admin of.) You (or another page admin) need to grant your app manage_pages and publish_pages, so that you can get a page token. Your app then needs to use that token to make the post _as_ the page. And, again, that means you need to do it server-side. If you put your page token into client-side code, everyone could find it there, and then use it do perform administrative function on your page.

Comment: I understand the logic now, and I can post to the page using the graph api tool, but when I do it from my app, the user access token returned from the 'facebook login' button is different, and returns a different page access token that the facebook graph tool one, and it fails.

Comment: It makes no sense to do that from within your iOS app. If you start with the user access token, you would only be able to get page tokens for the pages the current app user is an admin of - but you want to post to _your_ page. And using your page token to begin with, again, requires that you do this from a server.

Answer (score 1):

> regardless of who is using my IOS app - the end user may not even have
>   a facebook account.

Not Possible, User will have to have an Facebook account and after login they will be able to post to your Account see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755032/3798182) answer